# "No module named memcache" error in openstack newton keystone when accessing murano dashboard

Tags: python, django, openstack, fiware-murano

[**This image will help you to find the issue**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H63pc.png) I have configured Openstack newton on ubunu 16.04 LTS. It works fine
Now i have planned to integrate Murano in to this.
All progressed fine..When i am running dashboard using "**`tox -e venv -- python manage.py runserver <IP:PORT>`**" command. I am able to run the murano dashboard.

When i am accessing environment tab it displaying error

> Error: There was an error communicating with server.

And log message displays an error

> No module named memcache

For your reference error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/murano/murano/murano/api/middleware/fault.py", line 130, in
   process_request
return req.get_response(self.application)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py",
   line 1299, in send
application, catch_exc_info=False)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py",
   line 1263, in call_application
app_iter = application(self.environ,
   start_response)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py",
   line 130, in __call__
resp = self.call_func(req, *args,
   **self.kwargs)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py",
   line 195, in call_func
return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
   line 320, in __call__
response = self.process_request(req)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
   line 552, in process_request
resp = super(AuthProtocol,
   self).process_request(request)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
   line 348, in process_request
data, user_auth_ref =
   self._do_fetch_token(request.user_token)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
   line 388, in _do_fetch_token
data = self.fetch_token(token)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
   line 661, in fetch_token
cached =
   self._cache_get_hashes(token_hashes)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py",
   line 644, in _cache_get_hashes
cached =
   self._token_cache.get(token)
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/_cache.py",
   line 214, in get
with self._cache_pool.reserve() as cache:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
   return self.gen.next()
File "/root/murano/murano/.tox/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/_cache.py",
   line 78, in reserve
import memcache

ImportError: No module named memcache
```

**Can someone help on this?
Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Well, have you installed memcache?

Comment: If your configuration includes `memcached_servers`, make sure you install python_memcached in your tox venv (e.g do `tox -e venv -- pip install python_memcached>=1.58`)

Comment: Yes i have installed memcache in machine using apt-get

Comment: @tutuDajuju yes i haven't tried yet..when i tried to install python_memcached(tox -e venv -- pip install python_memcached>=1.58)on venv it returns nothing...

Comment: @tutuDajuju when i was try with out version name (tox -e venv -- pip install python_memcached) it installed successfully. But issue still persist

Comment: Are you sure the same exception occurs? Review & add the traceback to answer, or paste it into a gist.

Comment: @tutuDajuju Yes that was the same issue..

Comment: @tutuDajuju  

Please find the gist:

https://gist.github.com/gokul2993/542e1ab9fa05c1f0e77cd4f3e68359a7 

this was the full error message when i was run **tox -e venv -- python manage.py runserver <IP:PORT>**

Comment: Seems `memcache` is still missing `source /root/murano/horizon/.tox/venv/local/bin/activate && python -c "import memcache"` should raise the same exception

Comment: Is there any possible way to import memcache in venv?

Comment: @tutuDajuju Please find the image i have attached with it..It may help you to find

Comment: I just noticed that your tracebacks contain at least 2 different venvs. I guess you have to make sure to install memcache in each of them. OpenStack is weird.

Comment: Great tutuDajuju. Its working..I missed to install memcache in another venv...

Answer (score 2):

Just installing `memcached` is not enough. You will also need to install python memcache module which is provided separately by `python-memcache` and `python-pymemcache`. I am not sure which one is used here.

You can try installing them with `apt-get` and see which one works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Now working.. I have installed murano api and murano dashboard in different venv.
I have missed to install memcache in munano api venv. When i'm tried after install memcache in murano api venv..Now working fine..

@tutuDajuju Thanks for the Help...